# How to download and install drivers for CP210x USB to UART Bridge on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, esp8266

Firstly, I just want to say that any help is appreciated. I am trying to program the ESP8266 WiFi module with the Arduino IDE on my Ubuntu 16.04 PC. My problem is - being new to Ubuntu - how do I download the drivers from [this page](https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx#linux). When I downloaded them, I got the file like this:

[image]

But where do I go from here? Thanks!

Comment: did you try `make && make install` ?

Comment: Checked your HW ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux kernel already has a support for CP21x serial bridges. Do not need to do anything else. For communication issues, check your serial connection.